# Converting Hours passed to Current Time

Tags: java

I have a starting time (in this case 9 o'clock), and there are a certain amount of hours being added to it, and then the current time needs to be calculated. The current method that I am using is add the hours passed to the original time, then modulo by 12, like so: `timeAndHoursPassed % 12 = currentTime` this works well in all cases except for when the added time is divisible by 12, in which case I get the current time to be zero instead of 12. How can I fix this? In addition, if possible, I would prefer to use some basic math if possible, instead of using the GregorianCalender class.
Thanks for any and all help in advance.
My code is as follows:

```
package week11;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassingTrains {
    static int currentTime = 9, firstDistance = 0, secondDistance = 0, firstSpeed = 40, secondSpeed;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String passTime(){
        System.out.print("Enter the speed of the passenger train: ");
        secondSpeed = input.nextInt();
        while (currentTime < 11) {
            firstDistance += firstSpeed;
            currentTime++;
        }
        while (firstDistance > secondDistance) {
            firstDistance += firstSpeed;
            secondDistance += secondSpeed;
            currentTime++;
        }
        if (firstDistance == secondDistance){
            return ("at " + currentTime % 12);
        } else {
            return ("between " + (currentTime - 1) % 12 + " o'clock and " + currentTime % 12);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("The passenger train passed the freight train at " + passTime() + " o'clock");
            System.out.println("The freight train was traveling " + firstSpeed + " mph");
            System.out.println("The passenger train was traveling at " + secondSpeed + " mph");
    }
}
```

Comment: First, post your code.

Comment: @JasonC that suggestion does not work.

Comment: @hfontanez Post-edit, no it does not. Thanks for pinging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts:

1. You have to apply modulo 24 to the elapsed time. Why.  If you start at 9 o'clock today, and 24 hours elapsed, you add zero hours (24 % 24) and you have 9 o'clock the next day.
2. Let us assume 37 have elapsed.  Apply #1 above and you have 13 hours beyond 24.  Add 13 to 9 and you have 22 hours (10 o'clock PM).  If you don't want to use 24 hour calendar, subtract 12 from current hour IF current hour > 12.

Sample code:

```
currentTime += elapsedTime % 24; 
if(currentTime > 12) 
{
    currentTime -= 12;
}
```

**UPDATE**: OP's corrected code

```
public class PassingTrains
{
    static int currentTime = 9, firstDistance = 0, secondDistance = 0,
            firstSpeed = 40, secondSpeed, elapsedTime;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String passTime()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the speed of the passenger train: ");
        secondSpeed = input.nextInt();
        while (currentTime < 11)
        {
            firstDistance += firstSpeed;
            currentTime++;
        }
        while (firstDistance > secondDistance)
        {
            firstDistance += firstSpeed;
            secondDistance += secondSpeed;
            elapsedTime++;  // changed this

        }
        // added the next two lines
        currentTime += elapsedTime % 24;
        currentTime = (currentTime > 12) ? currentTime - 12 : currentTime;

        if (firstDistance == secondDistance)
        {
            return ("at " + currentTime); // fixed this
        }
        else
        {
            return ("between " + ((currentTime - 1 == 0) ? 12 : currentTime - 1) + " o'clock and " + currentTime); \\fixed this
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("The passenger train passed the freight train at "
                + passTime() + " o'clock");
        System.out.println("The freight train was traveling " + firstSpeed
                + " mph");
        System.out.println("The passenger train was traveling at "
                + secondSpeed + " mph");
    }
}
```